# UIImagePickerController both camera and library

Tags: iphone, ios5

I would have though that the UIImagePickerController would allow you to use the camera or choose from the library from within the view? It seems I have to pick one or the other cia the sourceType? Is there no way to add a button to the choose library view to switch to camera?

Comment: yup, there is a way, there are custom photo library, that you can duplicate the camera roll's function then add the camera button inside it via navigation bar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement this yourself. You can make a simple UISegmentedControl and when the value is changed, you change the source of the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: I was hoping to do it within the UIImagePickerController, can't I add a button to the bottom nav bar of that?

Comment: On an iPhone or iPod touch that bar is already pretty full. I think UIImagePickerController supports overlays, maybe you can do something with that.